# Why does my repository object return Nonetype with github3.py?

Tags: python, nonetype, github3.py

Using github3.py version 0.9.5 [documentation](http://github3py.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.5/repos.html), I'm trying to create a repository object but it keeps returning `Nonetype` and therefore I am unable to access the contents of the repository. There doesn't seem to be any other posts on StackOverflow, or conversations on the library's GitHub issues that address this problem.

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'contents'` is the exact error I received.

On the line that says `repo = repository('Django', auth)` I tried changing **auth** with **fv4** but that doesn't change anything other.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from github3 import authorize, repository, login
from pprint import PrettyPrinter as ppr
import github3
from getpass import getuser

pp = ppr(indent=4)


username = 'myusername'
password = 'mypassword'
scopes = ['user', 'repo', 'admin:public_key', 'admin:repo_hook']
note = 'github3.py test'
note_url = 'http://github.com/FreddieV4'

print("Attemping authorization...")


token = id = ''
with open('CREDENTIALS.txt', 'r') as fi:
    token = fi.readline().strip()
    id = fi.readline().strip()


print("AUTH token {}\nAUTH id {}\n".format(token, id))


print("Attempting login...\n")
fv4 = login(username, password, token=token)
print("Login successful!", str(fv4), '\n')


print("Attempting auth...\n")
auth = fv4.authorization(id)
print("Auth successful!", auth, '\n')


print("Reading repo...\n")
repo = repository('Django', auth)
print("Repo object...{}\n\n".format(dir(repo)))


print("Repo...{}\n\n".format(repo))
contents = repo.contents('README.md')


pp.pprint('CONTENTS {}'.format(contents))


contents.update('Testing github3.py', contents)

#print("commit: ", commit)
```

Comment: What are the results of your print? If you put in a `type(repo)` what do you get?

Comment: Sorry typo on my comment. I meant what do you get when you try to print repo and what do you see as a result of type(repo). is repository('Django', auth) returning anything? If repository() is your function, I think that that is where the debugging should occur. I have seen functions that return a None because the return statement is not executed.

Comment: @sabbahillel `<type 'NoneType'>`, which is why it crashes

Comment: That is why I suggested debugging in repository() and not at the usage of repo.

Comment: @sabbahillel [this](http://github3py.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.5/repos.html#github3.repos.repo.Repository) is the documentation for the repository object and [this](https://github.com/sigmavirus24/github3.py/blob/develop/github3/repos/repo.py) is the file for the **Repository** object. So... I tried changing the `repository()` call to `repos.repo.Repository('Django', auth)` after importing `repos`, but that results in a different error. Maybe I'm misreading the docs, but I thought that would work (though it does not).

Comment: **None of these objects should be instantiated directly by the user (developer). These are here for reference only.** It appears as if you are violating this instruction. Also below it seems to say that certain attributes are not returned. I am not familiar with this, but this may be your problem.

When listing repositories in any context, GitHub refuses to return a number of attributes, e.g., source and parent. If you require these, call the refresh method on the repository object to make a second call to the API and retrieve those attributes.

Comment: @sabbahillel Hmm...I guess I skipped over that completely. Though...that's a bit confusing. I'm not familiar with that either. I think I'm more confused than before. How can I then get the `contents` of a `repository` object? Like...how should I then be modifying my code?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you. perhaps the http://github3py.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.5/index.html can point you to the get request for a repository object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a few things up with your code, but let me help you with your immediate problem first and then I'll move on to the other issues.

You're using `github3.repository` in the line you're confused about. Let's look at the [documentation](https://github3py.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.5/api.html#github3.repository) for that specific function (which you can also see by calling `help(repository)`). You'll see that `repository` expects two arguments `owner` and `repository` and describes them as the owner of the repository and the name of the repository itself. So in your usage you would do

```
repo = repository('Django', 'Django')
```

But where does that leave your authentication credentials... Well here's the other thing, you're doing

```
fv4 = login(username, password, token)
```

You only need to specify some of those arguments. If you want to use a token then do

```
fv4 = login(token=token)
```

Or if you want to use basic authentication

```
fv4 = login(username, password)
```

Both will work just fine. If you want to continue to be authenticated you can then do

```
repo = fv4.repository('Django', 'Django')
```

Because `fv4` is a `GitHub` object which is documented [here](https://github3py.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.5/github.html#github-object) and which the `repository` function uses underneath everything.

So that should help you get through most of your problems.

---

Note that in the documented examples for github3.py we usually call the result of `login()` `gh`. This is because `gh` is just a `GitHub` object with credentials stored. It isn't your user or anything like that. That would be (on your version of github3.py) `fv4 = gh.user()`. (If someone else is reading this and using a version of github3.py 1.0 (currently in pre-release) then it would be `fv4 = gh.me()`.)

Comment: Ooooh OK. I understand now. I figured you'd end up answering, seeing as you're the maintainer. Thank you!